# alert id for jquery rates script

Tags: jquery

I'm using this script for rating:
http://antenna.io/demo/jquery-bar-rating/examples/

I chose the "Font Awesome" stars. I have several rates bar so I add ID to each one. When click on some star I would like to ALERT the right ID.

I tried this:

```
    rateID = $(this).parent(".br-wrapper").find(".rate-fontawesome").attr('id');
    $('.rate-fontawesome').barrating({
        theme: 'fontawesome-stars',
        showSelectedRating: true,
        onSelect:function(value, text) {
          alert('Selected rating: ' + value + 'ID: ' + rateID);
        }               
    });
```

but it's not working...

Comment: provide html template or prefered:jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` inside the `onSelect` handler refers to the `barrating` plugin object, which has a `$elem` property referring to the jQuery object corresponding to the changed rating element so you can try

```
$('.rate-fontawesome').barrating({
  theme: 'fontawesome-stars',
  showSelectedRating: true,
  onSelect: function(value, text) {
    alert('Selected rating: ' + value + 'ID: ' + this.$elem[0].id);
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks, it's looks good, but - can I put the value in variable? for instant: 
  rateID = this.$elem[0].id;

?